# x mark next to package in Atom's Resolver

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to get LaTeX to build in Atom and the usual key combo doesn't work.  I opened up the Resolver and it has a check next to the core keybinding but x-marks next to both the keybindings for the latex package and the latextools package.  Although I'm not sure I fully understand how I would change the order of precedence for these, I think the more pressing issue sounds like it's whatever's causing those x-marks.  Anybody have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keybindings in Atom work in the same way that CSS Selectors work, simply put this means that the *more* specific the selector the [higher it comes in the order of precedence](http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/):

> As is the case with CSS applying styles, when multiple bindings match for a single element, the conflict is resolved by choosing the most specific selector. If two matching selectors have the same specificity, the binding for the selector appearing later in the cascade takes precedence.

The keybinding resolver tells you which packages *could* have been triggered by the key sequence and which one "won out".  There are two ways you can affect which command comes top in the order of precedence.

### Changing your Keymap

1. Edit your `keymap.cson` by going to `File` → `Keymap...`
2. Add a **different** keymap that is otherwise unused or bind to a more specific binding, for example:

   ```
   "atom-text-editor[data-grammar='text tex latex']":
     'ctrl-;': 'latex-plus:compile-and-sync'
   ```
3. Save the file and test your keybindings.

### Disabling other Package Keybindings

If the keybinding that is interfering with LaTeX is in a package where you don't use **any** of the key bindings you can disable all of them:

1. Open settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>.
2. Click on the `Packages` tab.
3. Search for the package that is interfering with your keybinding.
4. Scroll down to `Keybindings` and un-check the `Enable` text box:

[image: Screenshot of Activate Power Mode disabled Keybinding]

If you are willing to be more specific about the exact packages you are using and the packages that are being triggered ahead of your desired command then I can be more specific with the steps required for your specific situation.

Comment: I'll try some of this out in a minute, but I think my issue is more than just precedence.  Part of that is because of the x-marks, which I think is indicating something bad happening.  In most other examples I've seen on the web, even when a command isn't being executed because something else takes precedence, the other commands still have a check next to them.  The other reason I think this is because I'm having huge troubles trying to delete my old version (it stopped working) and re-install it.  But whenever I delete my current version, not all of the associated files and folders get

Comment: deleted, and it causes my new installation to sometimes try to refer to old files and folders.

Comment: Are you able to post screenshots and examples of the problem, you may get a better response by posting on the [Official Forums](https://discuss.atom.io/).